# Auth::attempt() always returns false for default brand new installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried lot to search about the problem. I couldn't find any solution. Please help me to understand what i am doing wrong.

I am attaching the code:

**UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function signup(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password ')),
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            'state' => 'success',
            'message' => 'User created.'
        ],201);
    }

    public function signin(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));
        if (!$token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }
}
```

And i have routes in **api.php**

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function () {
    Route::post('signup', 'UserController@signup');
    Route::post('signin', 'UserController@signin');
});
```

I have 
[I have this in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XXH6.png)

I sent the below json to signup first, but then when i sent to signin i am getting failed.

```
{
    "name":"ironman",
    "email":"ironman@yahoo.com",
    "password":"avengers"
}
```

This is a brand new installation of laravel 5.4 (same with 5.5), Using detailt User migration and model came with it.

When i tried to diagnose the problem myself, i found that the password_very is returning false all the time in Auth package.

I am using default password field, hashing it while creating users as other similar questions answered.
I am using php artisan serv.
I am using postman to send this request.

Please help,

Comment: throw a `dd($request->only('email', 'password'));` in there and see if the inputs are coming through on the signin

Comment: @lagbox, thanks for responding. here is the output
`array:2 [
  "email" => "ironman@yahoo.com"
  "password" => "avengers"
]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pulling `null` from the request:

```
$request->input('password '); // notice the space

'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password ')),
```

You probably did not intend to put a space at the end of the input name:

```
$request->input('password'); // no space

'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you so much @lagbox

Comment: that should be it... i deleted my answer +1